# encoding error while running Sinatra

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, sinatra

I have my Sinatra-Redis Blog which had ran pretty well on my computer before I uploaded it on server. But I got the error that saying when I am running it on my server

"Encoding::CompatibilityError - incompatible character encodings: US-ASCII and UTF-8"

I found there are some answer like putting "#encoding:UTF-8" ahead my code, it doesn't work for me

I've tried to put ".force_encoding("utf-8")" after the values in my erb file, it works, but I don't think this is the only way to solve the problem, because I don't want to put ".force_encoding("utf-8")" after all my values.

Ruby version: 2.3.1
redis version:3.0.7
and I am using erb as my templating system.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encounter this problem many times. It runs pretty well on my localhost (MacOS) and found to have problem on the server(Debian). It is possibly because your server is using a different encoding setting.

You may want to change the encoding and restart your server.

Reference:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-203988/